# Modal tab does not load properly on first trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would expect this to work just fine. Runnable code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Text editor</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#signin" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Sign In/Register</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade bs-modal-sm" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <br>
        <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#signin" data-toggle="tab">Sign In</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#signup" data-toggle="tab">Register</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#why" data-toggle="tab">Why?</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="why">
              <p>We need this information so that you can receive access to the site and its content. Rest assured your information will not be sold, traded, or given to anyone.</p>
              <p>
                <br> Please contact <a mailto:href="JoeSixPack@Sixpacksrus.com">JoeSixPack@Sixpacksrus.com for any other inquiries.</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="signin">
              <form class="form-horizontal">
                <fieldset>
                  <!-- Sign In Form -->
                  <!-- Text input-->
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="userid">Alias:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input required="" id="userid" name="userid" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="JoeSixpack" class="input-medium" required="">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Password input-->
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="passwordinput">Password:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input required="" id="passwordinput" name="passwordinput" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="********" class="input-medium">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Multiple Checkboxes (inline) -->
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="rememberme"></label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <label class="checkbox inline" for="rememberme-0">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" id="rememberme-0" value="Remember me">
                    Remember me
                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Button -->
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="signin"></label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <button id="signin" name="signin" class="btn btn-success">Sign In</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="signup">
              <form class="form-horizontal">
                <fieldset>
                  <!-- Sign Up Form -->
                  <!-- Text input-->
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="Email">Email:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input id="Email" name="Email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="JoeSixpack@sixpacksrus.com" class="input-large" required="">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Text input-->
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="userid">Alias:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input id="userid" name="userid" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="JoeSixpack" class="input-large" required="">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Password input-->
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="password">Password:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input id="password" name="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="********" class="input-large" required="">
                      <em>1-8 Characters</em>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Text input-->
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="reenterpassword">Re-Enter Password:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input id="reenterpassword" class="form-control" name="reenterpassword" type="password" placeholder="********" class="input-large" required="">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Multiple Radios (inline) -->
                  <br>
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="humancheck">Humanity Check:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <label class="radio inline" for="humancheck-0">
                    <input type="radio" name="humancheck" id="humancheck-0" value="robot" checked="checked">I'm a Robot</label>
                      <label class="radio inline" for="humancheck-1">
                    <input type="radio" name="humancheck" id="humancheck-1" value="human">I'm Human</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Button -->
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="confirmsignup"></label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <button id="confirmsignup" name="confirmsignup" class="btn btn-success">Sign Up</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <center>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You can see that it is loading the tab pane because if you hover the mouse over the modal area you can see the cursor changes when over the invisible input boxes that it is not showing. Also, you can click on the other tabs, and return to the first one just fine. What's happening here?

Help?

Comment: Do you possibly have any other CSS besides the CDNs shown? I'm scratching my head a bit myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fade` effect causes your problem, just remove `fade` from the `tabpane` and it should work fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Text editor</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#signin" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Sign In/Register</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade bs-modal-sm" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <br>
        <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#signin" data-toggle="tab">Sign In</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#signup" data-toggle="tab">Register</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#why" data-toggle="tab">Why?</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane " id="why">
              <p>We need this information so that you can receive access to the site and its content. Rest assured your information will not be sold, traded, or given to anyone.</p>
              <p>
                <br> Please contact <a mailto:href="JoeSixPack@Sixpacksrus.com">JoeSixPack@Sixpacksrus.com for any other inquiries.</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane  active" id="signin">
              <form class="form-horizontal">
                <fieldset>
                  <!-- Sign In Form -->
                  <!-- Text input-->
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="userid">Alias:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input required="" id="userid" name="userid" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="JoeSixpack" class="input-medium" required="">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Password input-->
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="passwordinput">Password:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input required="" id="passwordinput" name="passwordinput" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="********" class="input-medium">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Multiple Checkboxes (inline) -->
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="rememberme"></label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <label class="checkbox inline" for="rememberme-0">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" id="rememberme-0" value="Remember me">
                    Remember me
                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Button -->
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="signin"></label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <button id="signin" name="signin" class="btn btn-success">Sign In</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="signup">
              <form class="form-horizontal">
                <fieldset>
                  <!-- Sign Up Form -->
                  <!-- Text input-->
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="Email">Email:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input id="Email" name="Email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="JoeSixpack@sixpacksrus.com" class="input-large" required="">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Text input-->
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="userid">Alias:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input id="userid" name="userid" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="JoeSixpack" class="input-large" required="">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Password input-->
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="password">Password:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input id="password" name="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="********" class="input-large" required="">
                      <em>1-8 Characters</em>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Text input-->
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="reenterpassword">Re-Enter Password:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input id="reenterpassword" class="form-control" name="reenterpassword" type="password" placeholder="********" class="input-large" required="">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Multiple Radios (inline) -->
                  <br>
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="humancheck">Humanity Check:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <label class="radio inline" for="humancheck-0">
                    <input type="radio" name="humancheck" id="humancheck-0" value="robot" checked="checked">I'm a Robot</label>
                      <label class="radio inline" for="humancheck-1">
                    <input type="radio" name="humancheck" id="humancheck-1" value="human">I'm Human</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Button -->
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="confirmsignup"></label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <button id="confirmsignup" name="confirmsignup" class="btn btn-success">Sign Up</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <center>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nice! Thank a lot, but do you know why? Is fade just not supported anymore?